# How to Supress SQLAlchemy Warnings when printing queries with stmt.compile?

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlalchemy

I like to log all the queries that occur in the event I want to debug them or run explain plans on them later.

For example:

```
from sqlalchemy import select
from sqlalchemy.dialect import oracle
queries = {}
# ...
sel = select([foo.c.id, foo.c.bar])
queries['foo query'] = sel.compile(dialect=oracle.dialect(), 
                                   compile_kwargs={'literal_binds': True})
results = conn.execute(select)
```

This always ends up outputting the following warnings:

```
SAWarning: Textual column expression 'id' should be explicitly declared
 with text('location'), or use column('location') for more specificity (this
 warning may be suppressed after 10 occurrences)
if guess_is_literal else "column"
```

Is there any way to suppress these warnings? Notably, I only want to suppress them in this very specific case of logging/printing the query, as opposed to a global suppression.

Answer (score 3):

You can suppress SQL Alchemy warnings messages in Python 2.7 like so:

```
import warnings
from sqlalchemy import exc as sa_exc

with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.simplefilter("ignore", category=sa_exc.SAWarning)
    results = query.execute()
```